# Tests with DBunit and Oracle 10g autogenerated primary key identifiers not synchronized (JPA/Hibernate)

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa, junit, dbunit

I'm testing a JPA/Hibernate application with DBunit and Oracle 10g. When I start my test I load to the database 25 rows with an identifier.

That's the xml where I have my data, that I insert with DBUnit

```
  <entity entityId="1" .... 
  <entity entityId="2" ....
  <entity entityId="3" ....
  <entity entityId="4" ....
```

That's my entity class with JPA annotations (not hibernate specific)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "entity")
public class Entity{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.Auto)
private Integer entityId;
...}
```

Those are the parameter values of the database connection with Oracle10g

```
jdbc.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.208.131:1521:database
jdbc.username=hr
jdbc.password=root
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
dbunit.dataTypeFactoryName=org.dbunit.ext.oracle.Oracle10DataTypeFactory
```

After insert this data in Oracle I run a test where I make Entity entity = new Entity() (I don't have to set manually the identifier because it's autogenerated)

```
@Test
public void testInsert(){

   Entity entity = new Entity();

   //other stuff

   entityTransaction.begin();
   database.insertEntity(entity);//DAO call
   entityTransaction.commit();

}
```

and when the test makes the commit of the transaction I get the following error

```
javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while commiting the transaction
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    ...
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:266)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1027)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:365)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:54)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00001: restricción única (HR.SYS_C0058306) violada

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwBatchUpdateException(DatabaseError.java:345)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10844)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
    ... 34 more
```

I have debugged it and the problem is that the entityId of the new object is 1, and already exists a entity with that Id. So, I don't know who is the responsable DBunit ? Oracle ? Why are not synchronized the identifiers of Oracle database and the identifier that JPA/hibernate gives to my entity in my testing code?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the AUTO generation type, in Oracle, is in fact a sequence generator. If you don't specify which sequence it must use, Hibernate is probably creating one for you and using it, and its default start value is 1.

Using AUTO is useful for quick prototyping. For a real application, use a concrete generation type (SEQUENCE, for Oracle), and create your sequences yourself with an appropriate start value to avoid duplicate keys.

Comment: Yes I can start the sequence from 26 value, but I don't want to do that because if my test changes and instead of adding 25 rows I insert 27 I'll have duplicate values too. Also I don't want my solution to be dependent of Oracle so I used Auto because in Mysql and HSQLDB works great (probably is not possible to be totally independent from the DBMS) Do you know why oracle is not updating the counter or like you say it's an hibernate problem ?? thanks

Comment: It's just how it works. The sequence generator uses the current sequence value, and assumes it's correct and won't cause duplicate keys. Either initialize the sequence yourself (you can use 100000 as start value if you want to be safe for your tests), or use negative IDs for the test data.

Comment: ok, I understand, but why does it work in Mysql and Hsqldb without a sequence?? Mysql and HSQLDB know that they have to continue from 26 value ... (curiosity)

Comment: Because with MySQL, AUTO relies on auto-increment columns, which start from the biggest value in the table. Hibernate inserts data without ID, and then ask the generated auto-increment value to MySQL after the insert. It's easier to use, but generates more queries than a sequence-based generation, which can cache sequence values for multiple inserts. I bet it's the same with HSQLDB.

Comment: So, it's impossible to have a single JPA implementation for MYSQL, HSQLDB and Oracle? is that true? In Oracle i'm forced to use GenerationType.SEQUENCE and in MySQL and HSQLDB I must use GenerationType.AUTO (SEQUENCE doesn't work)...

Comment: AUTO will work everywhere, but not the same way. It works on oracle, if you just configure the sequence with the appropriate start value.

Comment: It doesn't work with auto and a tableGenerator with initialValue=100 could be that the variable is an Integer?

Comment: Keep the code as it is. Just create the sequence with the initial value **in database**.

Answer (score 2):

You could use ids < 0 in your test data sets. Not only will your sequences never come in conflict with test records, but also you'll easily distinguish records that were inserted by the tests.

Answer (score 1):

The AUTO sequencing strategy usually defaults to the TABLE sequencing strategy, but in the case of Oracle, the sequencing strategy uses an Oracle sequence named `hibernate_sequence` (which is the default, unless you specify a sequence name in the strategy). The starting value of the sequence happens to be 1, which conflicts with the existing entity that is loaded using DbUnit, hence resulting in the `ConstraintViolationException` exception being thrown.

For the purpose of unit tests, you could perform either of the following:

- Issue a `ALTER SEQUENCE...` command to set the next value of the sequence, after loading data into the database. This will ensure that the JPA provider will use a sequence value that does not conflict with the existing Ids of the entities populated from your current XML file, by DbUnit.
- Specify the name of the sequence in XML file loaded as the `IDataSet` eventually used by DbUnit. The actual sequence values will have to be replaced in the `IDataSet` using a `SELECT <sequence_name>.nextval FROM DUAL`. The following section is reproduced as is and is credited to [this site](http://dbunit.wikidot.com/dbunitsupport):

> I spend a couple of hours reading the dbUnit docs/facs/wikis and
>   source code trying to figure out how to use Oracle sequences, but
>   unless I overlooked something, I think this is not possible with the
>   current implementation.
>
> So I took some extra time to find a workaround to insert Oracle
>   sequence generated IDs into dbUnit's datasets, muchlike what
>   ReplacementDataSet does. I subclassed DatabaseTestCase already earlier
>   in a abstract class (AbstractDatabaseTestCase) to be able to use a
>   common connection in case of insertion of my testcases in a testsuite.
>   But I added the following code just now. It looks up the first row of
>   each table in the dataset to determine which columns need sequence
>   replacement. The replacement is done on the "${…}" expression value.
>
> This code is "quick and dirty" and surely needs some cleanup and
>   tuning.
>
> Anyways, this is just a first try. I'll post further improvements as I
>   go, if this can be of any help to anyone.
>
> Stephane Vandenbussche
>
> ```
> private void replaceSequence(IDataSet ds) throws Exception {
>     ITableIterator iter = ds.iterator();
>     // iterate all tables
>     while (iter.next()) {
>       ITable table = iter.getTable();
>       Column[] cols = table.getTableMetaData().getColumns();
>       ArrayList al = new ArrayList(cols.length);
>       // filter columns containing expression "${...}"
>       for (int i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
>         Object o = table.getValue(0, cols[i].getColumnName());
>         if (o != null) {
>           String val = o.toString();
>           if ((val.indexOf("${") == 0) && (val.indexOf("}") == val.length() - 1)) {
>             // associate column name and sequence name
>             al.add(new String[]{cols[i].getColumnName(), val.substring(2, val.length()-1)});
>           }
>         }
>       }
>       cols = null;
>       int maxi = table.getRowCount();
>       int maxj = al.size();
>       if ((maxi > 0) && (maxj > 0)) {
>         // replace each value "${xxxxx}" by the next sequence value
>         // for each row
>         for (int i = 0; i < maxi; i++) {
>           // for each selected column
>           for (int j = 0; j < maxj; j++) {
>             String[] field = (String[])al.get(j);
>             Integer nextVal = getSequenceNextVal(field[1]);
>             ((DefaultTable) table).setValue(i, field[0], nextVal);
>           }
>         }
>       }
>     }
>   }
>
>   private Integer getSequenceNextVal(String sequenceName) throws SQLException, Exception {
>       Statement st = this.getConnection().getConnection().createStatement();
>       ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT " + sequenceName + ".nextval FROM dual");
>       rs.next();
>       st = null;
>       return new Integer(rs.getInt(1));
>   }
> ```
>
> My AbstractDatabaseTestCase class has a boolean flag
>   "useOracleSequence" which tells the getDataSet callback method to call
>   replaceSequence.
>
> I can now write my xml dataset as follows :
>
> ```
>   <dataset>
>    <MYTABLE FOO="Hello" ID="${MYTABLE_SEQ}"/>
>    <MYTABLE FOO="World" ID="${MYTABLE_SEQ}"/>
>    <OTHERTABLE BAR="Hello" ID="${OTHERTABLE_SEQ}"/>
>    <OTHERTABLE BAR="World" ID="${OTHERTABLE_SEQ}"/>
>   </dataset>
> ```
>
> where MYTABLE_SEQ is the name of Oracle sequence to be used.

Comment: Has this implementation ever made into official DBUnit release? This seems to be a long missing feature for Oracle users :-)